# WPF - How to get my Panel to see if a DependencyProperty is set on my child when they are UIElements?

Tags: wpf, panel, dependency-properties, uielement, measureoverride

Basically, during my `MeasureOverride` I want to check to see if my child element has a certain property set on it regardless of what type of item it is.

```
public override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
    {
        //Check for IsSelected property?
    }
}
```

How would one do this in a way to ensure that the child has the property available and then get the value for it? The problem is that UIElement does not have a IsSelected property and the panel can accept any child that supports that property, so I can't just cast to a specific type...

---

Well, I'm looking at 2 possible scenarios:

1) The child did not add itself as an owner of the `Selector.IsSelected` DependencyProperty, in which case that child is ignored entirely.
2) The child did add itself as an owner of the `Selector.IsSelected` DependencyProperty, in which case I want the that value.

Basically, I want the IsSelected value while also preventing my app from crashing in case there is no value associated to that child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the value of the [`Selector.IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.isselected.aspx) attached property? If so the following can help:

```
bool isSelected = (bool)child.GetValue(Selector.IsSelectedProperty);
```

Comment: I think so... I updated my question to better reflect what I want. But yes, ideally the child elements *should* add themselves as an owner of the IsSelected DP. Though, I want to take into account the situation where a child element was added that did not (in which case they get ignored).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `typeof(child).GetProperty("IsSelected")`

There's an MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) that you might find helpful too